# Problem with registering user through service with Passport in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am building registration form with Passport in Laravel using repository pattern, and when I try to register with postman I get error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\\Http\\Response::$id
```

It breaks when I try and return response like this

```
return response(['user' => $user, 'access_token' => $accessToken]);
```

but when I just return $user instead then it works fine, but I don't have access token then. How can I register succesfully with access token? Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

AuthController.php

```
public function register(RegisterUserRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $user = $this->service->createNewUser($request);
        
        return $this->returnResource($user);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return $this->failureJson($exception);
    }
}
```

AuthService.php

```
public function createNewUser(BaseRequest $request)
{ 
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $request['confirmation_hash'] = Str::random(50);
        $request['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);

        $user = parent::create($request);


        Mail::to($user['email'])->send(new ConfirmationMail($user)); // Send email to user to confirm his email!

        $accessToken = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

        DB::commit();

        return response(['user' => $user, 'access_token' => $accessToken]);  // HERE IT BREAKS!!!
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollBack();

        throw new \Exception($exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

UserResource.php

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'first_name' => $this->first_name,
        'last_name' => $this->last_name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'password' => $this->password,
        'remember_token' => $this->remember_token,
        'api_token' => $this->api_token,
        'confirmation_hash' => $this->confirmation_hash,
        'email_verified_at' => $this->email_verified_at,
        'is_verified' => $this->is_verified,
        'verification_expires_at' => $this->verification_expires_at
    ];
}
```

Comment: @RolandStarke nah, `$this` in that scope is the instance of the model

Comment: @PatricNox  Any clue?

Comment: I'm not that knowledged around services, but I suspect the resource is running on each key value. To verify, try to only return the access key. You said it worked if only returning the user, so my theory is that now when you try to return the access key it will give the same error.

Comment: If you ```dd($accessToken)``` , do you get the token ?

Comment: @EncangCutbray  Yes, I get the token when I dump accesstoken.

Comment: ```return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'access_token' => $accessToken]);``` what do you get if you run like this ?

Comment: @EncangCutbray Same thing, that error

Comment: Inside your ```createNewUser``` try to just return user ```return $user``` and then inside your ```UserResource.php```  create the token ```' api_token' => $this->createToken('authToken')->accessToken```

Comment: @EncangCutbray Yeah it passes now. In postman I see api token generated along user. But in database api_token column is null. Why is that when it shows in postman?

Comment: Glad to hear, because the token isn't save to database. You read this section for information ```https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/should-we-store-accesstoken-in-our-database-for-oauth2```. Happy coding

Comment: @EncangCutbray Okay so this works fine now? If so, post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: If you feel fine, it works, accept my answer, and you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `createNewUser` try to just return user `return $user` and then inside your `UserResource.php`  create the token `' api_token' => $this->createToken('authToken')->accessToken`